# Used and abused: What am I?

Tags: riddle

When you find me I come as one,

When you use me, I am two,

Many of you abuse me

Twice as many, refuse me

And like a pencil I have a use

What am I?

Hint:

> I'm more popular in some places than others

Spent a good amount of time on this one, are you up for the challenge?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution:

> Chopsticks

When you find me I come as one,

> When you buy them, come together

When you use me, I am two,

> you need to break them into two pieces

Twice as many, refuse me

> not all of us know how to use them

About the hint:

> In chinese or Japanese restaurants you can find it, but not italian

Comment: "And like a pencil I have use" They're also used/held in a similar way to pencil

Comment: yes, @ralt, but i didnt add it cause i found this line redundant after the "When you use me"

Comment: This was the correct answer!

Comment: Only cheap 1-time use wooden of that "thing" come as a single unit.